# Proper way of reading messages from Kafka topic and then closing

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

I am building a simple node.js API using express and kafka-node that returns unread messages from requested Kafka topic and consumer group when HTTP request is received and then closes the connection. I don't need or want the consumer to keep waiting for new messages.

In kafka-node, what is the proper way of checking if the end of the topic has been reached and if yes, close the connection to broker and exit the application in order to prevent new messages being read?

Here's my consumer.js. It's pretty much the same as example given in kafka-node documentation.

```
"use strict";

const kafka = require("kafka-node");

let topicName = "testTopic-01",
  groupName = "testGroup-01",
  consumerOptions = {
    kafkaHost: "localhost: 9092",
    groupId: groupName,
    sessionTimeout: 15000,
    protocol: ["roundrobin"],
    fromOffset: "earliest",
    encoding: "utf8"
  };

const consumerGroup = new kafka.ConsumerGroup(consumerOptions, topicName);

consumerGroup.on("message", message => {
  console.log(`Message: ${message.value}`);
});
consumerGroup.on("error", error => {
  console.error(error);
});

console.log(`Consumer started on topic ${topicName} on group ${groupName}`);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch the current offset of a **topic partition** by using [#Offset](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kafka-node#offset). By comparing the so fetched offset of your assigned topic partition, you then know what the last message in the corresponding topic partition is.

Keep in mind, that, if you have multiple consumers in parallel, you should keep track of the topic partition that your consumer inside the consumer group was assigned to ([#fetchCommits](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kafka-node#fetchcommitsgroupid-payloads-cb)).

Comment: I guess I could solve this by checking [latest offset for each partition in topic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kafka-node#fetchlatestoffsetstopics-cb) and compare it to l[atest committed offset in a consumer group](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kafka-node#fetchcommitsgroupid-payloads-cb). As long as the topic's latest offset is higher value than latest committed offset, there are new messages.

I'll try this out. Thanks!